# Creating new relationship so that only certain users can edit a document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a model "Trip" and I want to be able to have only certain users in "Group" create "comments".

When I first created the trip model, I had it set so that only one user can edit it. Now, I want to be able to invite other users to edit it as well. The part that is tripping me up (pun intended) right now  is that I have both `trip belong_to :user` (the user who created it) and `trip has_many :users, :through => :group`.

Questions:

1. Is this allowed per Rails convention?
2. Based on my model, group will have both user_id and trip_id. Is this the best way to approach this problem? That is, should there be a new record in the database for every user I invite to the group?

Thanks.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips, :through => :groups
  has_many :trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end
```

trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :traveldeal
  has_many :groups
  has_many :users, :through => :groups
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

view (show.html.erb)

```
<% unless @user.trips.empty? %>
  <% @user.trips.each do |trip| %>
    <!-- Content here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try `:through => :groups` instead of `:group`

Comment: My view no longer displays the error, but it is not displaying any trips that belongs to the user either. Made correction to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal `Rails` convention would have been to call the `Group` model something like `TripPerson` to specify the two tables that it was joining, but these join tables are a natural byproduct of relational databases. You'll have to continue creating a new `Group` object for every person invited to the trip.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I went back and changed my `Group` model to `TripUser`